# Magento homepage layout

Tags: html, xml, magento

For my project http://www.merekhayaal.com/ (Magento CMS) I am trying to get the Masonry layout and product sliders full width. They are currently 960px which is because they are contained in the div 'main'. The Masonry layout is getting its images from the class 'content', which apprarently linked to Content > HomePage > Pages > CMS > Magento.

When I try to move the 'content' class in 1column.phtml to outside 'main' (whose width is set to 960px) i get the desired result but it also causes content in other pages like Contact us, etc to go full width, which breaks the site design. 
Is it possible for a div to be bigger than its parent div? Any suggestions what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to create a new layout specifically removing the contained div "main", and assign it to your homepage.

**Documentation on how to create a new layout template:**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates

Answer (score 0):

I was running behind a similar solution, and I did the following: cloned the `[layoutcolumn].phtml` desired in `[package]/[theme]/template/page` and put the slider block within the div `page`, like this:

```
 <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[myslide]/[myslide]')->setTemplate('[myslide]/[myslide].phtml')->toHtml();?>

        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
            <div class="main">                                
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
```

So I did not lose the design of other blocks.
I don't know if it's the best solution, but it worked.